# How to add role of the user in oauth token (WSO2 IS)

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity server as IAM. In my angular application, I need samlsso, Hence I have implemented it and login is working as expected. Now, I want an authorization based on role(XACML policy) from the IS server. But in the token, I am getting following information only. There is no any information about user's roles and neither I have seen to configure it in console(While I am creating IDP).

Sample Token:

```
{
  "at_hash": "vYBW9************vg3uw",
  "aud": "rmSJ************xIHYWMVEYwa",
  "sub": "admin",
  "azp": "rmSJ************TpxIHYWMVEYwa",
  "amr": [
    "BasicAuthenticator"
  ],
  "iss": "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token",
  "exp": 1572779632,
  "iat": 1572776032,
  "nonce": "QG057mrPa*************************c2Eda",
  "sid": "*******-a7e6-48af-88e0-***********"
}
```

Here as you can see I have a username as sub(admin) but no roles of it.

Does anyone have any idea how to get them?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `http://wso2.org/claims/role` as a requested claim in the SP.

See [1] for more details.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+Claims+for+a+Service+Provider

Comment: I am getting this.  

[2019-11-05 11:03:09,017] [bfac11bf-d42b-484d-814f-92b85ad5dc07] ERROR {org.wso2
.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.Defau
ltRequestCoordinator} - Exception in Authentication Framework java.lang.IllegalS
tateException: Duplicate key http://wso2.org/claims/url
        at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:1
33)

Comment: This is how I made configuration and I am getting above error, Any idea about it  ?
Image url : https://ibb.co/LngT19F

Comment: You need to add `Requested Claims`.

Comment: Click on the green + button on your screenshot.

Comment: I don't see any requested claims added in above image.

Comment: I got it. Thanks mate!

Comment: Hi @Bee, It works with one domain, While in the case of multiple domains it's not working and ended up with HTTP Status 404 - /authenticationendpoint/claims.do
.Any idea ?

Comment: Please explain the issue further. What do you mean by domains?

Comment: Domain in the sense. I have multiple User Store Domains.

Comment: HI @Bee, Do you have any idea, There is any webservice in WSO2 IS, To clear the session for the user for specific serviceprovider.